# Order by and Group by with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

In my current code I'm using groupBy for a specific column and also I want to order each array by **order_no**. With my current code I get:

> "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not
> exist."

```
    $courses = CourseTopic::select([
        'course_topics.id',
        'course_topics.course_id',
        'course_topics.description',
        'course_topics.visible',
        'course_topics.name',
        'course_activities.order_no',
        'course_activities.activity_id',
        'activity_types.table_name'
    ])
    ->where('course_id', $course_id)
    ->leftJoin('course_activities', 'course_activities.course_topic_id', 'course_topics.id')
    ->leftJoin('activity_types', 'activity_types.id', 'course_activities.activity_type_id')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->orderBy('course_activities.order_no');
```

[image]

Comment: i think it should be sortby https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby

Comment: I tried and I get the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have them after `get()`, which means it is now a Collection query and no longer a QueryBuilder object. There are two options:

Move it before `get()`, so that MySQL does the ordering and grouping:

```
$courses = CourseTopic::select([
    'course_topics.id',
    'course_topics.course_id',
    'course_topics.description',
    'course_topics.visible',
    'course_topics.name',
    'course_activities.order_no',
    'course_activities.activity_id',
    'activity_types.table_name'
])
->where('course_id', $course_id)
->leftJoin('course_activities', 'course_activities.course_topic_id', 'course_topics.id')
->leftJoin('activity_types', 'activity_types.id', 'course_activities.activity_type_id')
->groupBy('course_topics.id')
->orderBy('course_activities.order_no')
->get();
```

Or use [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby), which is the Collection method. You'll need to use the returned column name instead of the MySQL relation

```
$courses = CourseTopic::select([
    'course_topics.id',
    'course_topics.course_id',
    'course_topics.description',
    'course_topics.visible',
    'course_topics.name',
    'course_activities.order_no',
    'course_activities.activity_id',
    'activity_types.table_name'
])
->where('course_id', $course_id)
->leftJoin('course_activities', 'course_activities.course_topic_id', 'course_topics.id')
->leftJoin('activity_types', 'activity_types.id', 'course_activities.activity_type_id')
->get()
->groupBy('id')
->sortBy('order_no');
```

Comment: Ok, I tried both methods. On the first one groupBy is not working, the response is not the same with the one from the img from my question.  For the second solution I get "Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::soryBy does not exist."

Comment: `soryBy` or `sortBy`?

Comment: Damn.. sorry, my bad. I have to use a foreach to access it, and from inside I'm using sortBy. Thank you!